# disable MenuStrip autohide on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drop-down-menu, menustrip

When i select any option from the drop-down of the Menu-strip control, the Code in its Click event is fired and the drop-down collapses. But i want that drop-down must stay open.

Please help

[image]

If i open a dialog on click of the item in this menu, the opened menu always remain in front of the dialog. How to send it to back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if the `Reception` is of type `ToolStripMenuItem` you can just do this :

```
Reception.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
```

You need to do that for Lab, Admin .. if you want the same effect for them.

PS : The Menu would stay open even if it loses focus. so you need to close it manually/programatically.

Alternatively (Which I think is more efficient), handle the closing event for the dropdown and cancel the closing if the [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownclosereason.aspx) is `ItemClicked`.

```
Reception.DropDown.Closing += new ToolStripDropDownClosingEventHandler(DropDown_Closing);

private void DropDown_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked || e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.AppFocusChange)
           e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: But i creates a problem, the dropdown dont close even after click on the Reception button

Comment: @Genius Ignore the first solution and use the second one.

Comment: I don't understand why e.CloseReason is AppFocusChange. What's going here. If I click on an item why is that setting state to AppFocusChange?